# In bash, How do I test if a word is not in a list?

Tags: bash, if-statement

Good day everybody,

I want to make an if conditional with the following aim:

*have two files, the script check a word of file1 (locate in variable $word2test) if exits in file2 (each word locate in variable $wordINlist) do nothing* **|** *if the word is not in file2, print it to stdout*

My first approach is:

```
if ! [[ "$word2test" =~ "$wordINlist" ]] ; then
    echo $word2test
fi
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple bash sample script :

```
word=foobar
grep -q "\<$word\>" FILE || echo "$word is *not* in FILE"
```

Another way with REGEX :

```
word=foobar
grep -q "^$word *$" FILE || echo "$word is *not* in FILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$wordINlist` is an array (you say "list" but I'm assuming you meant array), you can iterate through it like so:

```
for item in ${wordINlist[@]}; do
  [[ $item == $word2test ]] || echo $word2test
done
```

If `$wordINlist` is a file, then you can simply grep through it:

```
egrep -q "\b${word2test}\b" "$wordINlist" || echo "$word2test"
```

When `egrep` finds a match it returns true, otherwise it returns false.  So that simply says, "either a match was found, or echo `$word2test`"

If all you're wanting to do is see which items are in `file1` and NOT in `file2`, use `comm`:

```
comm -23 <(sort -u file1) <(sort -u file2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your files are simple lists of one word per line, try this:

```
grep -Fvf file2 file1
```

or

```
join -v 1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```